# Adjust vertical space between frames in beamerarticle

Tags: beamer, spacing, vertical-spacing, beamerarticle

When I create a handout version of my slides, the beamerarticle package inserts additional vertical space between frames, as in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
        Text
        
        More text
    \end{frame}

    % Additional vertical space inserted here
    
    \begin{frame}{}
        Even more text
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I get rid of this additional vertical space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spaces you see are introduced by the `{}` after `\begin{frame}`

[image: w]

Test this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}  

\begin{document}
        
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \frametitle{First: top aligned}
        Text
        
        More text
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[b]
        \frametitle{Second: bottom aligned}
        Text
        
        More text
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Third: default aligment}
        Even more text
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \textbf{Fourth:} frame without title
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \textbf{Fifth:} frame without title
    \end{frame}     
    
    \begin{frame}
        Text
        
        More text
    \end{frame}
    
    % Additional vertical space inserted here
    
    \begin{frame}
        Even more text
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Torben Wiedemann Please edit your question (new MWE) with all the variants you want to contemplate and the spaces you find and want to eliminate. Otherwise this will never end.

Comment: I edited the questions with a new MWE.

Comment: @Torben Wiedemann Please see the updated answer. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Wow. I thought the space between frames was a deliberate feature of beamerarticle, not a relic of my empty frame title. Thanks.